# How do I create a new "header file (.h)" in an existing "C++ Project" in "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, project

I can create such a file by opening a separate instance of studio, but I can't get my project to recognize it as an essential file in the side panel. I would prefer an answer by using studios own UI to create the file, but importing it will work as well if possible.

Note: I need an answer to Visual Studio year 2015. I have read that major program changes have been made since 2012/2013 and thus such solutions will probably not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project in project explorer (normally on the right) and choose `Add new item...`

Select C++ header file there.

Comment: Wow. Very simple!